# How can I create a database in SQL able to communicate with an android app?

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently started working on a project, where I am trying to create a linux web server that can communicate with an android app. I have gotten into the area of using SQL to create a database, which will be used by the app. I only got to this point because I am following a tutorial, so I don't have very much knowledge in creating databases with SQL at all. The tutorial eventually made me use phpmyadmin, which can be used to create databases for a specific server. Upon trying to create my own database, I came up with this error:

[image]

I got this error while trying to save the database, using this code:

`CREATE TABLE Parts.Parts ( ID INT( ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT ' v' , Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , part_nr INT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

**EDIT:**

Just so everyone knows, the link to the tutorial is here:

[Raspberry Pi Android App Communication](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Android-App-communication/)

My problem at the moment is under step four.

Also, does anyone know of an alternative that would be better suited for what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: The error speaks for itself. `INT( )` should be `INT` remove the parenthesis.

Comment: @cowbears101 You are suppose to accept answer

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax error. Just remove "()" after "INT".
Check the doc for more information: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/

To integrate a database with your app you app, you best create a web service to communicate with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is difference between database and table. The query, which you shared is for creating table not database.

Now, coming to actual question. You have couple of syntax error like

1. You need to specify the size of the `INT` or remove `()` after `INT`
2. You need to specify `ID` column as `primary key` as you have added `AUTO_INCREMENT` keyword.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Parts ( 
    ID INT(5) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT ' v' , 
    Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , 
    part_nr INT NOT NULL );
   ```

**>>>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2a41)<<<**